# DB Query no longer recognizes SQL parameters in existing application when debugging in VS2010

Tags: sql, db2

I just started working with an application that I inherited from someone else and I'm having some issues. The application is written in C# and runs in VS2010 against the 3.5 framework. I can't run the application on my machine to debug because it will not recognize the way they referenced their parameters when writing their DB queries.

For instance wherever they have a SQL or DB2 query it is written like this:

```
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
    "SELECT Field1 FROM Table1 WHERE FieldID=@FieldID", SQLconnection))
{
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("FieldID", 10000);
    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    ...
```

If you will notice the "parameters.AddWithValue("FieldID", 10000);" statement does not include the "@" symbol from the original command text. When I run it on my machine I get an error message stating that the parameter "FieldID" could not be found.

I change this line:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("FieldID", 10000);
```

To this:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FieldID", 10000);
```

And all is well... until it hits the next SQL call and bombs out with the same error. Obviously this must be a setting within visual studio, but I can't find anything about it on the internet. Half the examples for SQL parameter addition are written including the "@" and the other half do not include it. Most likely I just don't know what to search for.

Last choice is to change every query over to use the "@" at the front of the parameter name, but this is the transportation and operations application used to manage the corporation's shipments and literally has thousands of parameters. Hard to explain the ROI on your project when the answer to the director's question "How's progress?" happens to be "I've been hard at it for a week and I've almost started."

Has anyone run into this problem, or do you know how to turn this setting off so it can resolve the parameter names without the "@"?

Answer (score 1):

Success! System.Data is automatically imported whenever you create a .NET solution. I removed this reference and added it back to make sure that I had the latest version of this library and that fixed the issue. I must have had an old version of this library that was originally pulled in... only thing I can figure.

Answer (score 0):

Its handled by the .NET Framework data providers not Visual Studio.

It depends on the data source. Look here:[Working with Parameter Placeholders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy6y35y8.aspx)

You can try working with `System.Data.Odbc` provider and using the `question mark (?)` place holder. In thios case dont forget to add the parameters in the same order they are in the query.

Comment: Manji, thanks for the information. The MSDN page you posted has a lot of helpful info. Unfortunately, I am still confused though because I have 2 coworkers that can run the solution from their machines without any problems at all. According to the MSDN page, the SQL data provider requires the "@" symbol to be listed at the front of the parameter name. The other providers listed use the question mark like you mentioned above, except for the Oracle provider which is case insensitive. I went back to check and make sure we are in fact using the System.Data.Sqlclient library and we are.

Comment: If they can run it without any problems, then it makes sense that I should be able to as well. Kind of a weird situation, any ideas about why they can run it but I can't? Thanks again ahead of time.